# Run appcmd command from shortcut

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, shortcut

Very often I have to make following steps in command line (to identify correct worker process in IIS for debugging):

1. Run cmd as an administrator
2. cd %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv
3. appcmd list wp

I want to make a shortcut on the desktop to do it in one click.

How can I achieve that?

P.S. I tried to specify it like on the picture but it doesn't work, just opens cmd in inetsrv folder

[image: shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set up the shortcut to run as admin, so I do not go into details on that.

What is missing in your `Target` line is the switch to tell `cmd.exe` that there are strings following which should be interpreted and executed as command. You can chose `/C` for execute and quit (cmd window disappears) or `/K` for execute and show prompt (cmd window stays open). So the result would be something like: `"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /K "appcmd list wp"`. See `cmd.exe /?` for details.

GL, HF :)